# How to position elements correctly

Tags: html, css, position

Everything is fine when the page is full-screen, but if I resize the window the main-visual either forms a horizontal scroll bar or goes under the nav-bar that is on the left. I want to prevent this, and make it responsive.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

a,
a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Header */


/*============================*/

section .header {
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a5a0a0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: .3em;
  font-family: 'Lobster';
}


/* Navigation Bar
    ================================*/

section .nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  min-height: 100vw;
  min-height: 900px;
  background-color: #d4cccc;
  float: left;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%
}

.nav-bar ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #8c8983;
}


/* Main Visual
    ===================================*/

.main-visual {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 195px;
  width: 1100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
}

.main-visual img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!--  Link bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<!-- Lobster font -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">


<section>
  <header class="header container-fluid">
    <h1>Planes</h1>
  </header>
</section>

<section>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Facts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<div class="main-visual container-fluid panel panel-default">

  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x200" class="img-responsive">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis venenatis odio, vitae efficitur risus. Nunc ornare tristique est sit amet aliquet. Vestibulum id erat nec enim fermentum dignissim. Suspendisse suscipit eu mi sit amet pulvinar.
    Quisque porttitor arcu quis hendrerit hendrerit. Quisque ac tincidunt neque. Vestibulum consectetur eros id finibus porta. Pellentesque convallis sagittis tortor, ac gravida erat aliquam nec. Pellentesque quis elit id ipsum tempus sagittis. Quisque
    venenatis, velit eget blandit ornare, eros justo tincidunt tellus, at eleifend nibh dui et ante. Aenean pharetra feugiat libero, et laoreet lacus feugiat quis. Vestibulum ac imperdiet mi. Nunc consectetur diam erat, vel tempus eros eleifend ut. Nam
    elementum libero at sapien dignissim, sed bibendum enim commodo. Morbi vulputate, odio in semper maximus, mi lorem consectetur nisl, vitae fringilla magna lorem tristique est. Nulla nec rhoncus nibh, at laoreet magna.</p>

</div>
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/etasbasi/pen/rzLVeJ

And also make the nav-bar always fully cover the left pane, depending on the height of the main-visual.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use absolute positionning to build a layout untill you master (a mater of a couple of month ) :

- display (inline-block,table,table-cell,flex, eventually grid,...)
- float layout.

It only seems very simple at first to use `position:absolute;` , but its purpose is not to build an entire layout..

You can give a start with float (which can be odd too, [see this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) ) that will keep your elements in the flow.

to draw the column, you can use the [faux-column method](https://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) (oldish but solid here ).

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;*/
        /* background about : https://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #d4cccc 175px, transparent 170px)
}

a,
a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Header */


/*============================*/

section .header {
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a5a0a0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: .3em;
  font-family: 'Lobster';
}


/* Navigation Bar
    ================================*/

section .nav-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 175px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%
}

.nav-bar ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #8c8983;
}


/* Main Visual
    ===================================*/

.main-visual {
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-visual img {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <header class="header container-fluid">
    <h1>Planes</h1>
  </header>
</section>

<section>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Facts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Category</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<div class="main-visual container-fluid panel panel-default">

  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x200" class="img-responsive">

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin venenatis venenatis odio, vitae efficitur risus. Nunc ornare tristique est sit amet aliquet. Vestibulum id erat nec enim fermentum dignissim. Suspendisse suscipit eu mi sit amet pulvinar.
    Quisque porttitor arcu quis hendrerit hendrerit. Quisque ac tincidunt neque. Vestibulum consectetur eros id finibus porta. Pellentesque convallis sagittis tortor, ac gravida erat aliquam nec. Pellentesque quis elit id ipsum tempus sagittis. Quisque
    venenatis, velit eget blandit ornare, eros justo tincidunt tellus, at eleifend nibh dui et ante. Aenean pharetra feugiat libero, et laoreet lacus feugiat quis. Vestibulum ac imperdiet mi. Nunc consectetur diam erat, vel tempus eros eleifend ut. Nam
    elementum libero at sapien dignissim, sed bibendum enim commodo. Morbi vulputate, odio in semper maximus, mi lorem consectetur nisl, vitae fringilla magna lorem tristique est. Nulla nec rhoncus nibh, at laoreet magna.</p>
</div>
```

A block aside a float doesn't need a width nor a margin to be set if you mind the [block formating context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) (overflow is used here in the snipppet

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I have two questions: In this code what makes the nav-bar take the full length of the web page? And what code makes the main-visual responsive, or is that its default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a defined width set (1100px for .main-visual), that will stay fixed as you resize the page thus causing it to overflow to the left of the screen as you noted earlier. There are a few things you can do to fix this:

1. Set a percentage width which will cause the element to change based on the width of the browser. So width: 80% will cause the element to take up 80% of the width of its parent element which is the body in this case.
2. Use the max-width property instead of setting a width. This means that as the browser page gets larger, the element will grow with it until it reaches a maximum width. I would also suggest you add some padding: 0 10px; so the text doesn't flow to the edge of the screen using this method.